# Errno 13 Permission denied, when trying to save an image to media_root

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I have hosted my python + django project on pythonanywhere.com and I have encountered a problem, when I want to save an item with an image. All other fields of `item` are saving, but the image isnt.
Here's the whole error:

`PermissionError at /admin/core/bike/add/`

`[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/omega/resizedComm/media_root/bikes/xx.png'`

My settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_root')
```

What can be causing this error?

Ok, so when I change the `MEDIA_ROOT` to different path it actually works (it creates the folder and upload images there), but it crashes when I am trying to save the image to the oryginal `media_root`. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the user your script is running with have write access to `'/home/omega/resizedComm/media_root/bikes/`?

Comment: @Matthias I dont really understand the question, do you mean like a superuser? When I run the app on localhost, everything is working fine.

Comment: @OmletteDuFromage Do you have access to your files on server?

Comment: @ParantapParashar well I can access the files from the pythonanywhere panel, do I have to grant access somewhere else?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /home/omega/resizedComm/media_root/bikes`?

Comment: @DannyStaple it says `dr-xr-xr-x 2 omega registered_users 4096 Jun 19 21:54`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error and the output of ls would suggest that the folder you are trying to write to, does not have write permissions.

Either manually, or through code you'll need to grant write permissions. If your code is running as omega, then `chmod u+w <folder path>` should do it. In python, chmod with the numeric code 755 should do it.

```
import os
os.chmod(<folder path>, 755)
```

Comment: `chmod u+w <folder path>` worked, thank you